# Fix screen orientation to portrait

Tags: android, android-manifest, screen-orientation

I know this might sound as a thousand times answered question but I am really confused because this should be so easy that I don't understand what's going on.

I want one of my activities shows only in portrait mode. I thought, ok, just write in the AndroidManifest.xml something like this:

```
<activity android:name="Control" android:screenOrientation="nosensor">
    </activity>
```

And that's all.

But the app ignores it. It switches to landscape when I turn the device. I am using ActionBarSherlock, Fragments and ViewPager.

How can I fix the orientation of the Activity? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

we fix like this

```
<activity android:name=".Control" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
   </activity>
```

your Activity name Must Be

```
 android:name=".Control"
```

Comment: I changed the name to just "Control" because with ".Control" didn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` ?

Comment: Yes, that's why I was trying with "nosensor" and with the activity name to Control instead of .Control.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in your manifest.

Comment: Actually I copied/pasted the nosensor option because I was sick of trying with "portrait". It didn't work.

Comment: Did you place it in the activity tag?

Comment: Yep, this is an extract of my AndroidManifest:

`<activity android:name=".Control" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>´

Maybe it has something to do with SherlockActionBar or Theming?

Comment: I'm not sure, try changing the theme and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so this was another of my typical Logic errors.

If you have a Fragment with a ViewPager that contains another three Fragments it doesn't matter if you try to change the behaviour of any of the embeded Fragments because it won't work, logically. If you set screenOrientation to portrait on the main Fragment with the ViewPager that contains the other you will, now yes, prevent app from changing orientation.